# Qt anonymous signals

Tags: c++, oop, qt, signals

Is it possible to send signals to a slot without connecting them?
There is a class that has a SLOT which shows some logs.
For now we don't have any information how many classes will be use to send signals to this log slot, and we won't be able to address their objects to each other, but every objects might send logging request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call an object's (public) slot just like you call a normal member function. A connection is not necessary.

Besides, you don't need to know in advance who will connect to a given slot. The connection can happen outside your class. (For public slots at least.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you may, in a few ways.

You may call the slot like any other C++ function (if it is `public`).  Slots are still C++ functions.  The downside is that the caller needs to know the receiver's interface at compile time.

```
logger.log("The frobnitz could not be quuxed");
```

You may invoke the slot via `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`.  With this method, the caller doesn't need any compile-time info about the recipient other than the fact that it is a `QObject*`.

```
if (!QMetaObject::invokeMethod(logger, "log", Q_ARG(QString, "The frobnitz could not be quuxed"))) {
    qWarning("Internal error: logging failed (did someone change the logger API?)");
}
```

Comment: While it's true that you can just call a slot as with any normal method (because it is a normal method), this solution is much cleaner, because it will actually queue the action and let the event loop handle it. It's the way to go when passing messages between threads, and if you need some more dynamic message passing.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such possibility. But maybe you can just make log() method static, so you will be able to call log() method without referencing logger object?